# How to create a Chromogram-like chart in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a chart using R like this one. The description said this is a chromograms, but I couldn't find any resources or examples of creating this type of chart online.

I have the time of all the events and their categories, the only thing I need to do is to plot every single event based on the time and date. I tried to tweak things like geom_lines() and geom_boxplot(), but they all gave me a stacked bar instead of a distribution of events. geom_points() can achieve something close to what I want, but they are all points instead of single lines/bars.

An example of data would be:

```
Study Period  Hour of day  Event
Day 1         7:00         Add an activity
Day 1         9:00         Delete an activity
Day 2         8:00         View timeline
Day 3         11:00        View timeline
```

....

Comment: Please provide some example data in a plain text format (using _e.g._ `dput`) so we have something to work with.

Comment: @neilfws Okay I just added. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Looks like you could do this with `ggplot(SOME_DATA, aes(PARTICIPANT, DAY_TIME, color = EVENT)) + geom_tile() + facet_wrap(~SYSTEM)`. I suggest you combine `Study Period` and `Hour of day` into a single numeric column do you can use them like DAY_TIME here.

Comment: @JonSpring What do you mean by "facet_wrap(~SYSTEM)"?  I thought facet_wrap(~) is just something that wraps the plot into multiple sub-plots?

Comment: The original plot looks like it has two facets, relating respectively to "Full System" and "App-only System." I'm assuming the specification between the two is represented in a variable called, say, "SYSTEM."

Comment: @JonSpring You are right, wrap_facet can separate the plot by groups. But my question here is actually how to plot individual events by day and time. I tried to tweak things like geom_lines() and geom_boxplot(), but they all gave me a stacked bar instead of a distribution of events. geom_points() can achieve something close to what I want, but they are all points instead of single lines/bars.

Comment: perhaps `geom_tile(aes(PARTICIPANT, DAY_TIME, fill = EVENT), width = 1, height = H)`. The value of H would depend on the frequency and numeric format of your time stamps, so it might for instance need to be 3600 if your y axis is POSIXct and you want the notch to represent 1 hour of seconds.

Comment: @JonSpring Yes it works!! The line is too light at the beginning, but after I added "position=position_dodge(width=0.5)" it worked as expected! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a chart like this using `geom_crossbar`. First, let's make some data that resembles yours.

I've included a column `Subject`, labelled the events A-F and assumed that all timestamps are the same format as your example data (H:M).

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1001)
df1 <- data.frame(
  Subject = sample(as.character(1:8), 100, replace = TRUE),
  Event = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 100, replace = TRUE),
  Day = paste("Day", sample(1:28, 100, replace = TRUE)),
  Time = paste0(sample(0:23, 100, replace = TRUE), ":00"))
```

First, combine the day and hour into one variable which I named `decDay`:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(D = as.numeric(gsub("Day ", "", Day)), 
         H = as.numeric(gsub(":00", "", Time)), 
         decDay = D + H/24) %>%
  head()

  Subject Event    Day  Time  D  H   decDay
1       7     C Day 13  1:00 13  1 13.04167
2       3     B Day 19 12:00 19 12 19.50000
3       7     C Day 19  7:00 19  7 19.29167
4       7     A Day 27  5:00 27  5 27.20833
5       8     F Day 25 17:00 25 17 25.70833
6       7     C Day 20  0:00 20  0 20.00000
```

We can pipe that result to `ggplot`. Note that in `stat_summary` we supply the same value to `fun.y`, `fun.ymin` and `fun.ymax`. `max` is used here but it could be any function that returns the unaltered value of `decDay`.

`scale_y_reverse` is used with parameters to generate a y-axis that looks like the example chart in the question.

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(D = as.numeric(gsub("Day ", "", Day)), 
         H = as.numeric(gsub(":00", "", Time)), 
         decDay = D + H/24) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Subject, decDay)) + 
  stat_summary(geom = "crossbar", 
               fun.y = max, 
               fun.ymax = max, 
               fun.ymin = max, 
               aes(color = Event), 
               width = 0.8) + 
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = c(1, 28), 
                  labels = c("Day 1", "Day 28")) + 
  labs(y = "Study Period (Day 1-28)")
```

Result:

[image]